# How to set up table keys (indexes) in Mysql DBs in the right way

Tags: mysql, indexing

I would like to know how keys in a MYSQL table should be constructed and created to ensure the most efficient search.

Suppose I have a table with the fields:

a , b , c , d

and I use in my SELECT statement all kind of possible combinations of these fields in the WHERE condition.

Is it better to create a single combined key which covers all fields ?

Or should I better create a key for each of the four fields ?

Which variant has a better performance for the search query ?

The key(s) should only be of type INDEX.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

My [*cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) covers some basics.

> I use in my SELECT statement all kind of possible combinations of these fields in the WHERE condition.

That is not practical.  Instead, get some experience with the UI and decide which 2 columns are typically queried on.  Then have an `INDEX(x, y, ...)` where x and y are the most common.

If both x and y are tested with `=`, it does not matter which you put first.  Otherwise, put the `=` one first.  If neither is tested with `=`, then having more than one column won't help.

Please provide a hint of your app.  Real estate?  Matchmaking?  Something else?

> Is it better to create a single combined key which covers all fields ?

Rarely.  The order of the columns *in the index* matters.

> Or should I better create a key for each of the four fields ?

Maybe.  You may as well tack on more columns, based on what combos are likely.

> Which variant has a better performance for the search query ?

We need to talk around specific examples.

> The key(s) should only be of type INDEX.

Huh?  "key" and "index" are synonyms.

**More**

Since the values are "continuous" "scientific" values, you should probably use `FLOAT` for datatypes.  And you will probably be mostly comparing with ranges (eg, pH < 5.0).

When using a composite index, the index stops being useful after the first "range".  Hence, you probably cannot do better than having 4 1-column indexes.  (Let's see some typical examples of your queries.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rick James for your explainations. They are helpful. My tables are about scientific data. Parameters like pH, salinity, and so on where it matters to combine the parameters in all possible ways.

Comment: Those sound like values that are best stored as `FLOAT`.  But do not test with = or !=; there are rounding issues that make such tests likely to give unexpected results.  (I added to my Answer.)